# How to get the memory address of a rendered image?

Tags: memory, rendering, unity-game-engine

I develop a simulator in Unity which has to communicate with another application. The problem is that I have to render a camera manually and send the obtained image to the other application, which takes too long.

My question: is there a way to get the memory address where the obtained image is? I need this to read the image directly from the other application in order to reduce the time of the transmission.

Comment: have you tried Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr.html

Comment: But wont be there access denied exception when you try to read memory reserved for other application? Of course depends on the OS and the rights given to the app, but still question remains.